# unable to start spring boot web application

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, reactive-programming, gretty

I am trying to create a basic application that would use `Spring Boot` and `reactive programming` (and without `web.xml`)

This is my `servlet`

```
public class RootServlet extends ServletHttpHandlerAdapter {
    public RootServlet(HttpHandler httpHandler) {
        super(httpHandler);
    }

    public RootServlet() {
        this(WebHttpHandlerBuilder
                .webHandler(toHttpHandler(routingFunction()))
                .build()
        );
    }

    private static RouterFunction<?> routingFunction() {
        return route(GET("/ping"), new PingHandlerFunction());
    }

}
```

This is my `handler function`

```
public class PingHandlerFunction implements HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> {
    @Override
    public Mono<ServerResponse> handle(ServerRequest request) {
        return ok().body(fromObject("true"));
    }
}
```

And this is my `application`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.lapots.tree.model" })
public class TreeModelApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TreeModelApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() throws Exception {
        ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new RootServlet(), "/");
        registrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registrationBean.setAsyncSupported(true);
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

I put properties into `resources/application.properties`

```
server.port=8080

logging.level.root=INFO

spring.application.name=tree-model-test
```

To start web application I use `gretty` plugin

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'

gretty {
    springBoot = true
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:$springBootVersion"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBootVersion"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:$springBootVersion"

    providedCompile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:$servetApiVersion"
}
```

Where `springBootVersion=2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` and `servletApiVersion=4.0.0-b03`

But when I try to start application using `gradle jettyRun` I get this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/web/SpringBootServletInitializer
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.findClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:510)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:441)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.FilteringClassLoader.loadClass(FilteringClassLoader.java:62)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:403)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at java_lang_Class$forName.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyServerConfigurer.createContext(JettyServerConfigurer.groovy:118)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyServerConfigurer$createContext$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyServerConfigurer.createAndConfigureServer(JettyServerConfigurer.groovy:68)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyServeurer.createAndConfigureServer(JettyServerConfigurer.groovy)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyServerConfigurer$createAndConfigureServer.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyServerManager.startServer(JettyServerManager.groovy:41)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.ServerManager$startServer$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.run(Runner.groovy:117)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSi
te.java:210)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.main(Runner.groovy:44)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(r.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:450)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.FilteringClassLoader.loadClass(FilteringClassLoader.java:62)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:403)
        ... 46 more       
Exception in thread "Thread-3" org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\b
in\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:366)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileOperations.javaexec(DefaultFileOperations.java:159)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.javaexec(AbstractProject.java:784)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.javaexec(AbstractProject.java:780)
        at org.gradle.api.Project$javaexec$6.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.DefaultLauncher.javaExec(DefaultLauncher.groovy:89)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:382)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1015)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.LauncherBase$_launchThread_closure4.doCall(LauncherBase.groovy:256)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.LauncherBase$_launchThread_closure4.doCall(LauncherBase.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:292)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1015)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:504)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Make sure you have spring-context jar in Maven Dependencies library. Which spring boot parent you are using?

Comment: @KumareshBabu added in question gradle dependencies

Comment: Oh Okay. This error shows java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - specific class is not found in the package. Please make sure spring-context jar is added in classpath.

Comment: @KumareshBabu but shouldn't spring boot include it in `starter-web` application?

Comment: @KumareshBabu added `compile 'org.spring.framework:spring-context:5.0.0.RC1` and still get this exception

Comment: Spring Boot will include spring-context jar. Sometimes based on spring boot version it is not fetching jar properly. I tried using with 1.5.2 it doesn't include spring-context related packages but jar is present in classpath - it is empty. Then I changed to 1.5.3 - it works!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143871/discussion-between-kumaresh-babu-and-user1432980).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the discussion with @KumareshBabu we found out that in earlier versions of `spring boot` the class `SpringBootServletInitializer` was located in `org.springframework.boot.context.web` while now it is located in `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support` package.

So I decided to use workaround [gretty/issue-334](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/issues/334)

Answer (score -3):

Go to **http://start.spring.io/** and add dependencies and create your project and simply import that project in eclipse .